# /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have searched the problems with this tag already and i believe that my problem is something else. I am using eclipse juno to build a C++ project. To check compatibility i used a small project to test. i  got these 2 errors
 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found
 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version`GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found
i checked for version of gcc compiler using gcc --version and it is 4.1.2
i checked for included path in eclipse juno and i found
[IMG]http://i62.tinypic.com/33dhv69.png[/IMG]
As you can see i have included the path  for include files for this compiler too
where lies

---

the mistake?

Comment: It looks like you're compiling with one version of GCC, but the shared libraries are for another version.

Comment: how can i check that and how do i configure it to use shared libraries from the same version

Comment: It's probably quicker and more painless to just purge everything to do with GCC from your system and reinstall the package.